# AngularJS passing boolean to directive is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have a directive that is used for adding a gradient background colour which is a bit like this:

```
.directive('colouredTile', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'ColouredTileController',
        scope: {
            colour: '@colouredTile',
            colouredIf: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {

            console.log(scope.colouredIf);

            // Get the CSS to apply to the element
            var css = controller.generateCSS(scope.colour);

            // Apply the CSS to the element
            element.attr('style', css);
        }
    };
})
```

I am currently trying to add an **ng-if** type function to it, so I added an attribute called **coloured-if**. I would like it to only apply the colour when the **coloured-if** property is evaluated as true.
I know I will have to add a watch, but I haven't got that far yet.
So far I have this in my view:

```
<form name="orderHeader" novalidate coloured-tile="D83030" coloured-if="orderHeader.$invalid" ng-class="{ 'test': orderHeader.$invalid }">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : !orderHeader.source.$pristine && orderHeader.source.$invalid || !orderHeader.source }">
        <label class="control-label">Source</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="source" ng-disabled="controller.order.orderNumber" ng-model="controller.order.source" ng-options="source.id as source.name for source in controller.sources" required></select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : !orderHeader.reason.$pristine && orderHeader.reason.$invalid || !orderHeader.reason }">
        <label class="control-label">Reason for adding additional order</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="reason" ng-disabled="controller.order.orderNumber" ng-model="controller.order.reason" required>
            <option>Manual</option>
            <option>Sample</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : !orderHeader.accountNumber.$pristine && orderHeader.accountNumber.$invalid || !orderHeader.accountNumber }">
        <label class="control-label">Account number</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="accountNumber" ng-disabled="controller.order.orderNumber" ng-model="controller.order.accountNumber" typeahead="account.accountNumber as account for account in controller.autoComplete($viewValue)" typeahead-template-url="template/typeahead/typeahead-account-match.html" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : !orderHeader.referenceNumber.$pristine && orderHeader.referenceNumber.$invalid || !orderHeader.referenceNumber }">
        <label class="control-label">Customer reference number</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="referenceNumber" ng-disabled="controller.order.orderNumber" ng-model="controller.order.referenceNumber" required />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" ng-click="controller.back()">Cancel</button>
        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-disabled="orderHeader.$invalid" ui-sref=".lines">Continue</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, I have the **coloured-tile** on the form itself and the **coloured-if** property is evaluating the form's **$invalid** state.
If the form is invalid I want it to apply the colour.

The problem is, at the moment, in my directive where I console log out the **scope.colourIf** it is returning "undefined" which is odd. As a test, I added an **ng-class** directive to the form to see if the form has access to the **$invalid** property and I can confirm it does.

So, does anyone know why I am getting "undefined" and not "true" in my directive?

Comment: need to watch `coloredIf` ... you only ever evaluate it once. Not sure why you don't just use `ng-style` for this, you are essentially recreating a directive that is already built in

Comment: when your link function runs the forms $invalid property hasn't been set yet

Answer (score 0):

The `link` function is executed when the DOM is parsed however the value of your directive `colouredIf` may changed during the use of your application. Therefore you need to `$watch` for changes on this variable:

```
scope.$watch('colouredIf',function(newVal,oldVal){
   console.log(newVal);
});
```